# Deceptively not-as-simple-as-I-thought typing

Tags: haskell

In the process of writing an interpreter in Haskell for a separate, simple programming language - I find myself butting my head against a wall as I learn typing in Haskell.

I have two custom data types

```
data Expr
    = Var Var
    | NumE Int
    | NilE
    | ConsE Expr Expr
    | Plus Expr Expr
    | Minus Expr Expr
    | Times Expr Expr
    | Div Expr Expr
    | Equal Expr Expr
    | Less Expr Expr
    | Greater Expr Expr
    | Not Expr
    | Isnum Expr
    | And Expr Expr
    | Or Expr Expr
    | Head Expr
    | Tail Expr
    | Call String
    deriving (Show, Read)

data Val = Num Int | Nil | Cons Val Val
    deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

and I'm starting to write the cases for interpreting these options, with the function interpret_expr

```
interpret_expr :: Vars -> Expr -> Val
interpret_expr vars@(Vars a b c d) (NumE integer) = integer
```

but this COMPLAINS that it couldn't match expected type 'Val' with actual type 'Int' in the expression 'integer'. But say I change it to something silly like

```
interpret_expr :: Vars -> Expr -> Val
interpret_expr vars@(Vars a b c d) (NumE 'a') = 'a'
```

it then complains at 'a' that it can't match expected type 'Int' with actual type 'Char'. NOW IT WANTS AN INT?????? I really don't know what to say, I really thought it would be as simple as providing NumE with a variable it could figure is an integer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `Val` type? You don't show that definition.

Comment: In your first `interpret_expr`, you said it should return a `Val`, but you are trying to return an `Int`.  You forgot to apply your constructor `Num : Int -> Val`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case you are returning an `Int` from a function you declared to return a `Val`. From your definition of `Val` it looks like you probably want to return `Num integer` here.

In the second case the problem is in the pattern matching. `(NumE 'a')` is an error because `NumE` is defined as `NumE Int`, so it must be followed by an `Int`, not a `Char`.

Comment: Ok this is the right answer. Adding a "Num" specifier like so interpret_expr vars@(Vars a b c d) (NumE integer) = Num integer, clears the error. I am getting confused by the Haskell error messages, telling me there is a problem at (NumE integer), rather than a probelm at (= integer)

Comment: Haskell's error messages are confusing at first sadly. You do get used to them pretty quick.

Comment: @nebffa yeah it's because of the way type inference works.  All it knows is that the return type of `interpret_expr` and the type of `integer` should be the same but they aren't, but it doesn't know which one is wrong.

Comment: @luqui so what you're saying is that when I see a Haskell type error message, the error could be in one of two places, right? So I don't have to go searching just where Haskell says the problem was found

Comment: @nebffa, yeah -- not always two though.  It's good at pointing to the right spot often, but not always.  Look at the other uses of the identifier it is pointing to, also.

Comment: @nebffa If Haskell complains about two types not matching it'll tell you the expression. Your code will contain a reason why that expression should be the first type, and a separate reason why that expression should be the second type. Identifying those reasons is how you find the problem. Usually both reasons are nearby to the spot Haskell found the error (and often one of them is a type declaration you gave, so you just need to find the other one).

Comment: @nebffa i.e. in your `NumE integer` case, the problem was that if `integer` was pulled out of `NumE integer` it must be an `Int`. But the return type you promised for `interpret_expr` was `Val`, and you returned `integer`, so `integer` must be a `Val`. Those two facts can't both be true at the same time, hence the error.

Comment: @nebffa: It might help to think of it as a "round peg in a square hole" error. GHC doesn't know which (if either) is the right shape, it just knows they don't fit together. In the first case you're putting an `Int`-shaped peg in a `Val`-shaped hole as the value of the expression; in the second case your pattern match says you want a `Char`-shaped peg in an `Int`-shaped hole as the argument. The "actual" type is the peg (expression), the "expected" type is the hole (context the expression is used in).

Comment: @C.A.McCann Thanks for the explanations guys. It is becoming clearer now what Haskell means when it says something